# In Terraform 0.12 validation doesnt work with count variable

Tags: validation, count, terraform

main.tf:

```
variable "name" { default= "" }

resource "null_resource" "validate_name" {
  count = "${length(var.name) < 1 ? 1 : 0}"
  "Please provide valid name value" = true
}
```

terraform plan

Error: Invalid argument name

on main.tf line 4, in resource "null_resource" "validate_name":
   4:   "Please provide valid name value" = "true"

Argument names must not be quoted.

Above code was working terraform 0.11 version.
Please suggest solution to make it working with TF0.12

Comment: That code wouldn't have worked in Terraform 0.11 because `"Please provide valid name value"` isn't a valid argument name for the `null_resource` resource. Can you share what you had as actual working Terraform 0.11 code?

Comment: Very dirty question.Please, use a standard framework for your question.

Comment: With tf0.11 when value is blank, scritp was throwing below error
Error: null_resource.validate_name: : invalid or unknown key: Please provide valid name value , 
it was solving my purpose. In case value is present,script was getting executed successfully.
but in 0.12 it throws error even though value is present. Please suggest if I could make my use case working with tf0.12

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of considered a hacky workaround for performing assertions in earlier versions (e.g. 0.11) of terraform.

In `0.12` the project maintainers have recently merged an [experimental feature](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/23794) that makes these types of assertions first-class.

For more history and background on assertions in terraform, see [this github thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15469).